# Проиграть звуковой файл только при зажатой кнопке

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь сделать драм машину

Подключил словари с привязанными к клавиатуре кнопками и ссылками на звуки.
Обработчик проигрывания звука такой

```
private void x_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sound = "";
        string name = (sender as ToggleButton).Name;
        if (sounds.TryGetValue(name, out sound))
        {
            new SoundPlayer(sound).Play();
        }
    }
```

Но, если нажать на кнопку то звук играть не будет, он заиграет если отпустить кнопку, но это плохо, хочется чтобы звук играл только тогда, когда зажата кнопка и переставал играть когда кнопку отпустили. Подскажите как решить данную задачу?

Comment: Добавлю, повесил на поток плеер, хотел добиться результата чтобы при нажатии двух кнопок обе играли, а не одна из них       ` private void x_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sound = "";
            string name = (sender as ToggleButton).Name;

            if (sounds.TryGetValue(name, out sound))
            {
                sp.SoundLocation = sound;
                Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    sp.Play();
                });
                thread.Start();
            }

        }`

Comment: результатов нет ( может кто подскажет как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен, использована библиотека mwp.dll